# Spring MVC : Error 404 Bad Request while trying to pass List of Integer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc, arraylist

I am trying to pass the following request to server from angular js.

```
var params_for_unread={
                method:'POST',
                url:"/chat/unread/count",
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type' :"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                data: $.param({
                    tenantIdList:tenantIdList,
                    propertyId: item.id
                })
            }
$http(params_for_unread).then(function(response1) {
                console.log(response1.data);
            })
```

This is corresponding to the following request in java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/unread/count",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<Integer> getUnreadMessages(
@RequestParam("tenantIdList") List<Long> tenantIdList,
@RequestParam("propertyId") Long propertyId){
    return chatDataService.loadUnreadMessages(tenantIdList,propertyId);
}
```

The details of header of the request passed from the browser is a follows

```
 **Form data**
 tenantIdList[]:1
 propertyId:1
```

I am getting exactly,what I want at the header,but still getting bad request.Another additional information I can provide is the way,I formed the list to be passed.

```
var tenantIdList = $scope.tenant_on_chat.map(function(e){return e.id;});
```

After trying different combinations,I could not find an exact solution to fix this Bad Request.

Comment: Check content-type of java service, maybe it's not a "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", so filters reject your request

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Vlad.However,I have used the same "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for other requests while using RequestParam annotation in Java. The possible issue I believe is while passing values to arraylist tenantIdList[]